# Color the datagridview there where it found a difference with SQL

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview, colors, sql-server-2016

I got some code which makes an SQL query and pastes the result into a datagridview. This works perfectly. The code be seen below:

```
private void FillInDataGrid()
{
        string cn =     ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Scratchpad"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(cn);

        string sql =

        "SELECT " +
        " dbo.new.[column1], dbo.new.[column2], dbo.new.[column3], dbo.new.[column4] from dbo.new" +
        "except " +
        "select dbo.old.[column1], dbo.old.[column2], dbo.old.[column3], dbo.old.[column4] from dbo.old"
        ;

        SqlDataAdapter dataadapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, myConnection);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        myConnection.Open();
        dataadapter.Fill(ds, "Authors_table");
        myConnection.Close();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
        dataGridView1.DataMember = "Authors_table";
}
```

This code displays the values of the row from the `new table` if it doenst exists in the `old table`. Now I want to color the cells where they differ. So for example if you have those two tables:

```
new table:
--------------------------------------
| column1 | column2| column3| column4| 
--------------------------------------
| 1       | 1      | 1      | 2      |
--------------------------------------
| 2       | 2      | 3      | 2      | 
--------------------------------------
| 6       | 7      | 9      | 8      | 
--------------------------------------
| 7       | 5      | 34     | 22     | 
--------------------------------------
| 3       | 4      | 3      | 3      | 
--------------------------------------

old table:
--------------------------------------
| column1 | column2| column3| column4| 
--------------------------------------
| 6       | 7      | 9      | 8      | 
--------------------------------------
| 7       | 5      | 34     | 22     | 
--------------------------------------
| 1       | 1      | 1      | 1      |
--------------------------------------
| 2       | 2      | 2      | 2      | 
--------------------------------------
| 3       | 3      | 3      | 3      | 
--------------------------------------
```

So this example would show:

```
--------------------------------------
| column1 | column2| column3| column4| 
--------------------------------------
| 1       | 1      | 1      | *2*    |
--------------------------------------
| 2       | 2      | *3*    | *2*    | 
--------------------------------------
| 3       | *4*    | *3*    | *3*    | 
--------------------------------------
```

Where the * 2 *, * 3 * and * 4 * would show a color in the datagridview.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: How would you like the query output to look like?

Comment: What orders the rows in your input data?

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz The same as its now, I dont want to change the query, unless I need to change it to give those cells a color

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz the orders of my rows are completely random

Comment: I totally lost you.

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz I used SQL queries in C# and those queries are working, but the output of the datagridview (windows forms), I want to color those

Comment: What links your old and new table? For example, yes if you compare row 1 from the old table, with row 1 from the new table, the only difference is column 4, but why does it have to be row 1 and row 1, since the order is completely random, why not compare row 1 from the old table to row 2 from the new table, where all four values are different?

Comment: @GarethD True, actually none of the rows in the new table compare to the old table. A row from the new table is just comparing every single row of the old table, to see if it found a match or not. If it doenst found a match it will be showed. I updated the tables a tiny bit to maybe give a better expression

Comment: At row 1 of the final table, it will highlight the last value, because the first 3 ARE found. And at row 2 of the final table, it will highlight the third column because the first 2 values ARE found.

Comment: Yes, but how do you know to only compare the row (1,1,1,2)` in the new table to the row `(1,1,1,1)`, in the old table, if you compare to the row `(3,3,3,3)`, then none of the values are found, therefore all the cells should be highlighted.

Comment: @GarethD Youre right, I guess I should probably rewrite my SQL query to first only check column 1, then check column 1 and 2 and so forth.